# struts2 interceptors and webservlets

Tags: java, servlets, struts2, interceptor, struts2-interceptors

Is it possible to use a Struts2 interceptor for a page that doesn't have an action associated with it? Trying to implement an interceptor so all users must login. Yet the other pages in my site are webservlets and do not rely on actions or struts. How can I achieve that? I don't really want to create actions and action classes just to use an interceptor.

Comment: Using S2 as a security framework?? Try spring-security or something similar.

Comment: If your entire site is servlets then what does Struts have to do with anything? Use a filter or Spring security or whatever.

Comment: well if I knew that I would not be asking the question. I don't use Spring or Struts. I just want to have a logon page where users can't access the other couple pages without logging in first and creating a session.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Struts2, you should use primarily Actions, that are thread-safe and that work through an Interceptor Stack.

You can use Servlets for particular cases only, not for the default flow. If you do that, you are not using the framework, so you can't expect using any of its mechanism like Interceptors.

You can by the way use a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) (Interceptors are based on that technology), handling the thread-safety in the Servlets by yourself.

The question is: why ?

Comment: The only need I have for the framework is to implement a logon system with some security. Everything else works fine with simple webservlets and Rest services. Is there a way to include the simple pages so that only a user with a valid session can access them? I don't know much about the struts framework...